# I need popup message like map info window

Tags: android

I am unable to find the way to create a popup like info window in map . I have to use it to show the three button inside

1. Yes
2. later
3. No

these three options are  clickable.
The pop up will show above three  button in vertical manner  in recycler view . I have created recycler view and  pop up view but how to show it like a Tooltip with clickabe

Answer (score 1):

you can use PopupWindow, its starting with API +23

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#FFBBFFBB" android:orientation="vertical" > <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp" android:text="Hello My Window" android:textSize="20sp" /> <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp" android:text="Button" android:textSize="20sp" /> </LinearLayout>
```

class

```
package com.example.hellopopupwindow;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Context mContext = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContext = this;

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                showPopupWindow(view);
            }
        });
    }

    private void showPopupWindow(View view) {

        // A custom layout, as the display content
        View contentView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.pop_window, null);
        // Set the button click event
        Button button = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "button is pressed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(contentView,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);

        popupWindow.setTouchable(true);

        popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                Log.i("mengdd", "onTouch : ");

                return false;
                // It returns true if the words, the touch event will be blocked
                // PopupWindow onTouchEvent interception is not called, so click on the external area cannot be dismiss
            }
        });

        // If you do not set the PopupWindow background, both the external region click or Back keys are not dismiss box
        // I think there is a bug API
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.selectmenu_bg_downward));

        // After setting the parameter to show
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(view);

    }

}
```

[image]